# How to define a trigger in H2 database

Tags: database, spring-boot, triggers, h2

It's been few days now that I'm working on write a trigger without success.

I have 2 spring boot microservices, the first one contains configuration to share H2 database (with one table myTable) to the second (by tcp connection)

```
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public Server inMemoryH2DatabaseaServer() throws SQLException {
    return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
}
```

This configuration works well, the second service can access to the database and make requests. After that, I wrote a trigger (inside file data.sql) inside the second service for INSERT inside myTable but it didn't work

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS ING_TRIGGER
AFTER INSERT
ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
CALL "com.example.Calculator.trigger.MyTrigger";
```

And this MyTrigger class

```
    public class MyTrigger implements Trigger {


    @Override
    public void init(Connection connection, String s, String s1, String s2, boolean b, int i) throws SQLException {
        Trigger.super.init(connection, s, s1, s2, b, i);
    }

    @Override
    public void fire(Connection connection, Object[] objects, Object[] objects1) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("--- INSERTION WAS DONE ---");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        Trigger.super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() throws SQLException {
        Trigger.super.remove();
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my configuration ?

Comment: What didn't work? It should be in the `schema.sql` not `data.sql`. That being said what doesn't work? You get an error? No trigger? Or something else.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, my trigger doesn't trigger, i don't see "INSERTION WAS DONE" in the console. Moreover, I define schema.sql in first service and I define the trigger in the second service inside data.sql

Comment: Shouldn't the trigger class be part of the first service? As that is running the DB and containing the code.

Comment: @M.Deinum I made the choice to define the trigger in another service because I want to separate the business logic related to the trigger

Comment: Nice that you want to seperate but how is H2 aware of that code? It can only access code on the classpath of the service that launches it. Also why did you need to seperate it in the first place, why not just an embedded H2 in 1 service?

Comment: @M.Deinum My project is constituted by several microservice and each of them have a logic and 2 of those microservices share an H2 database